# Why is a request to a @RequiresUser not redirected to the login page?

Tags: jersey, jetty, guice, shiro

The setup is as follows: An embedded Jetty 9.3.0.M0 runs a GuiceServlet 3.0, which in turn uses Jersey 1.18.1 for mapping and all the other nifty stuff it can do. Shiro 1.2.3 was added to this setup to provide security. When doing the configuration of Shiro in general and the filterChains in a ShiroWebModule, the setup works flawless.

When using Shiro's AOP feature to annotate my methods with [Shiro's annotations](http://shiro.apache.org/java-annotations-list.html), requests to the annotated method's URL do not get redirected to the login page. Instead, an [org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/shiro/authz/UnauthenticatedException.html) exception is thrown by Jersey's ContainerResponse:

```
ERROR com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse -
The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response,
re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException: Attempting to perform a user-only operation.
The current Subject is not a user (they haven't been authenticated or remembered from a previous login).  Access denied.
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.UserAnnotationHandler.assertAuthorized(UserAnnotationHandler.java:61)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:84)
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:67)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.invoke(AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException: Not authorized to invoke method: public java.lang.String org.example.product.ExampleApp.controller.Index.secured()
at org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.assertAuthorized(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:90)
```

The browser shows an `javax.servlet.ServletException: Filtered request failed.`.

However, an according Jersey ExceptionMapper is implemented and bound:

```
/* other imports omitted for readability */
import org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthenticatedException;

public  class UnauthenticatedExceptionHandler
                implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthenticatedException>{

  public Response toResponse(UnauthenticatedException exception) {      
    return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .entity("Authorization required").build();
  }
}
```

so even when Shiro does not redirect the request to the login page, the ExceptionMapper should trigger, which it doesn't. The bound ExceptionMappers for `NotFoundException` et al work.

The necessary MethodInterceptors are defined and bound in a module, which gets installed in my "main" module:

```
/* imports ommitted for readability */
public class ShiroMethodInterceptorModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiresRoles.class),
            new ShiroMethodInterceptor(new RoleAnnotationMethodInterceptor()));
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiresUser.class),
            new ShiroMethodInterceptor(new UserAnnotationMethodInterceptor()));
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiresPermissions.class),
            new ShiroMethodInterceptor(new PermissionAnnotationMethodInterceptor()));
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiresGuest.class),
            new ShiroMethodInterceptor(new GuestAnnotationMethodInterceptor()));
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RequiresAuthentication.class),
            new ShiroMethodInterceptor(new AuthenticatedAnnotationMethodInterceptor()));
  }

}
```

The implementation of ShiroMethodInterceptor (shamelessly copied from @pabiagioli['s "shiro-guice-jersey-bootstrap" project](https://github.com/pabiagioli/shiro-guice-jersey-bootstrap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pampanet/sample/shiro/modules/ShiroMethodInterceptor.java)) is as follows:

```
public class ShiroMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor{

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShiroMethodInterceptor.class.getName());

private org.apache.shiro.aop.MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor;

public ShiroMethodInterceptor(org.apache.shiro.aop.MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor) {
    this.methodInterceptor = methodInterceptor;
}


  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    return methodInterceptor.invoke(new ShiroMethodInvocation(methodInvocation));
  }

  private static class ShiroMethodInvocation implements org.apache.shiro.aop.MethodInvocation {

    private final MethodInvocation methodInvocation;

    public ShiroMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
        this.methodInvocation = methodInvocation;
    }

    public Object proceed() throws Throwable {
        return methodInvocation.proceed();
    }

    public Method getMethod() {
        return methodInvocation.getMethod();
    }

    public Object[] getArguments() {
        return methodInvocation.getArguments();
    }

    public Object getThis() {
        return methodInvocation.getThis();
    }
  }
}
```

The project is build with maven, and the relevant dependencies defined are:

- jersey-guice 1.18.1

  - guice 3.0
  - guice-servlet 3.0
  - jersey-servlet 1.18.1
- shiro-core 1.2.3
- shiro-web 1.2.3
- shiro-guice 1.2.3
- shiro-aspectj 1.2.3

*Edit:* For being complete: The Realm is created by an according provider, the ShiroWebModule's configure method looks like this:

```
protected void configureShiroWeb() {

    bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.loginUrl"))
            .to("/login");

    addFilterChain("/", ANON);

    addFilterChain("/login", AUTHC);
    addFilterChain("/logout", LOGOUT);

    /* The following rule is activated when not using AOP
     * annotations
     * addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);
     */

}
```

I'd really appreciate any pointers. Please do not hesitate to ask for further information.

*Edit2: This may be unrelated, but I add it here for completeness.* Further investigating this problem I noticed that if wrong or empty credentials are given even when I configure Shiro completely in a ShiroWebModule and disable annotations and AOP altogether, as far as I can see a Runtime Exception exception is thrown which is cought by jersey and wrapped into a WebApplicationException:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:41)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:41)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Any answer to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common error with the authc filter. It needs to be configured to filter all of your URLs, otherwise it is not available to them.  Try this:

```js
addFilterChain("/logout", LOGOUT);
addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it, and the difference is that all requests (even the ones annotated with `@RequiresGuest`) are redirected to the login page. The annotations are not ignored, however, since I tried `@RequiresRoles`. But instead of displaying the configured `roles.unauthorizedUrl` (bound as a constant in the ShiroWebModule), an Exception is thrown: `javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException: Subject does not have role [admin]` - though I have an UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implemented and bound. I am not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Additionally to the filters installed through the ShiroWebModule, I had everything filtered through GuiceShiroFilter, too. Now, the RequiresGuest annotation works (will have to implement an Anonymous annotation ;) ). However, the ServletExceptions for non matching authorizations are still thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation-based authorization assertion logic is not currently web-aware.  You have 2 options:

1. Configure your web framework of choice to catch the exceptions as they bubble up and redirect as expected, or
2. Use Shiro's servlet filter-based assertion framework (as you appear to have configured).

To make this a more 'out of the box' working experience, the Shiro servlet filter implementations need to be modified to catch known Shiro exceptions as they bubble up and re-direct the end-user to a known location - please open a Jira issue to capture this work.  HTH!